# Merge multiple dataframes in Python on key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have three dataframes with `Date_Final` as column under them all. I want to merge them all and Currently, my code is. I want to merge these dataframes into a single dataframe where firstly I create a new dataframe from any stock's dataframe.

What should be the optimized code?

```py
    df_stockanlaysis = stock1[['Date_final']]
    df_stockanlaysis = pd.merge(df_stockanlaysis, stock1, how='left', on ="Date_final")
    df_stockanlaysis = pd.merge(df_stockanlaysis, stock2, how='left', on ="Date_final")
    df_stockanlaysis = pd.merge(df_stockanlaysis, stock3, how='left', on ="Date_final")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a reduce, pandas and list comprehension.
Put those dataframes in a list like

```
dfs = [df_stockanlaysis1, df_stockanlaysis2, df_stockanlaysis3]
```

and the common column in this case i assume its 'Date_final'

```
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='Date_final'), dfs)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked as a charm! Just to add for anyone who may be looking to replicate such a situation using `functools.reduce` and `import functools` is required